# Keep user logged in state if user hard codes url

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to update my navbar component so that bar buttons change based on if a user is signed in or not.

I included the show/hide bool in my data like this:

```
data() {
    return {
        showDropdown: false,
    }
}
```

And I have a computed component set up like this:

```
computed: {
    btnPressed: function() {
        if (sessionStorage.token != null) {
            return this.showDropdown = true
        }
    }
}
```

I also have an eventBus set up from the created() hook in the navbar component so what when user logs in from the home page, it causes the showDropdown variable to switch to true

```
created() {
     eventBus.$on('btnPressed', (user) => {
         this.showDropdown = true
         this.user = user
         console.log('btn pressed')
     })
}
```

If I log in from the login page, it works fine but then if I manually type in example.com/users, showDropdown gets reset and doesn't get set back even though I still have my token.

EDIT:
My navbar component template is as follows:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
  <v-toolbar clipped-left>
    <v-menu>
      <v-toolbar-side-icon class="hidden-md-and-up" slot="activator" >
      </v-toolbar-side-icon>
      <v-list>
        <v-list-tile-title>test</v-list-tile-title>
      </v-list>
    </v-menu>
    <v-toolbar-title @click="$router.push('/')"><v-btn flat>Home</v-btn></v-toolbar-title>
    <v-spacer></v-spacer>
    <v-menu v-if="showDropdown" offset-y>
      <v-btn slot="activator" flat> {{ user }} </v-btn>
      <v-list>
        <v-list-tile @click="$router.push('/users')">Users</v-list-tile>
        <v-list-tile @click="">test3</v-list-tile>
        <v-list-tile @click="">Logout</v-list-tile>
      </v-list>
    </v-menu>
    <v-toolbar-items class="hidden-sm-and-down">
      <v-btn flat disabled>Link Two</v-btn>
      <v-btn slot="activator" flat disabled>Link Three</v-btn>
    </v-toolbar-items>
  </v-toolbar>
  </div>
</template>
```

EDIT 2:

This is what my App.vue template looks like as well:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <Navbar></Navbar>
    <transition name="fade">
    <router-view/>
    </transition>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Take a look here. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage. I would consider switching to localStorage to avoid this issue and encrypt a dictionary with your token, expiry datetime and a salt.

Comment: @PaulThomas I am using localStorage, I explain how in  my question. Token is stored in local storage, the problem is having the navbar check for it on page reload

Comment: No, you are using session, this behaves differently, manual intervention by user can reset. (`sessionStorage.token != null`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little bit of troubleshooting, I found one of the issues was that the syntax should be `sessionStorage.getItem('token')` and then I needed to put additional checks in the mounted hook like this:

```
if (sessionStorage.getItem('token') != null) {
          return this.user = sessionStorage.getItem('user')
        }
if (sessionStorage.getItem('token') != null) {
          return this.showDropdown = true
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution to your problem as i have experienced such before is to create mounted property for the bar button so that it is hidden/shown depending on the state of the token

```
 mounted(){
     eventBus.$on('btnPressed', (user) => {
             this.showDropdown = true
             this.user = user
             console.log('btn pressed')
         })
        }


 created(){
       if (sessionStorage.token != null) {
                return this.showDropdown = true
            }
    }
```

Comment: still does not work if I manually type in www.domain/users the page changes and the button disappears even though I still have token in storage.

Comment: Ok i think, you will have to abstract your component out so that you can load it dynamically. Can you share your button bar source code. So i can edit my answer.

Comment: I included my template for the navbar component, I have the mounted, created and computed methods in there as well from above.

Comment: I also included what my App.vue template looks like with where I put my navbar.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185772/discussion-between-precious-okwu-and-nick).